# How does this implicit conversion in C++ takes place?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, implicit-conversion

I'm new to C++.When I was reading, I came across this snippet.

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
void swap(int& num1,int& num2)
{
    cout<<&num1<<"\n";
    int temp=num1;
    num1=num2;
    num2=temp;
}

int main()
{ 
    int num1=1,num2=4;
    swap(num1, num2);
    cout<<num1<<"\n"<<num2<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

My doubt is we are passing only the values.How does the address get passed?Kindly clear me this basic doubt.

Comment: It's called a reference. They're syntactically cleaner pointers that can guarantee they're not null, usually. You use them differently, but they're the same thing underneath.

Comment: You aren't passing values, you are passing the variable by reference. This is similar to passing the address of the variable as a pointer, but with different syntax. As far as the compiler is concerned, they probably compile the same.

Comment: PS there is standard function `std::swap` you can use.

Comment: btw first line of "swap" function prints **address** of 'num1' and not its **value**

Comment: Think of the variables as boxes with numbers in them. The "&" means that instead of the function receiving the contents of the boxes, it is taking the actual boxes. When you get them back, the function has replaced the contents.

Comment: Try calling: `swap(10,20);`. A reference is a reference, bound to a variable. A constant cannot be a reference.

Answer (score 4):

There is no implicit conversion taking place. You are just passing an `int` by reference instead of by value.

Have a look through [this tutorial](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/). It's relatively short and gets the idea across.

Comment: Earlier I have studied that if I need to pass by reference,I need to call the function like `swap(&num1,&num2)`.Clear me this doubt.If I pass `swap(num1,num2)' which one will be passed? Value or address or both?

Comment: If you want to pass by reference, you just call the function as `swap(num1, num2)`. Then you make sure the function is defined as `swap(int& num1, int& num2)`. If you call the function as `swap(&num1, &num2) you are actually passing the addresses of the variables, so the function would need to be `swap(int* num1, int* num2)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically passing by reference and reference is just an alias to that int ( You can say another name assigned to that memory ). So, anything you do with that alias is reflected to the memory for which it is alias to ( in this case your original int )

Answer (score 1):

Re

> **”** How does the address get passed?

it isn't, necessarily.

For example, chances are that your compiler will inline the function call in the machine code, and treat each reference as simply an **alias** for whatever's referred to.

But in many cases such optimization isn't possible, and *ad hoc* schemes such as numbering the possible bindings and so on aren't really practical, so the general implementation of a reference, at the machine code level, is a memory address.